# Stability of Netty 3.5.0

Tags: java, netty

I see there is only 1 issue left on the netty 3.5.0 release.

I don't need to half close a socket, I just need the file upload functionality. Is the code stable enough for me to be able use the file upload stuff safely?

Also, what is the expected time for releasing 3.5.0? You folks seem to be moving fairly quickly these days, si it seems like it might not be long.

Comment: not a good question for SO as relevant to only a single instant in time (too localised). you should ask this kind of question on the appropriate Netty development list or similar

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the list for netty questions of all sorts, there is nothing else on their site.

Comment: https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/netty-dev

Comment: OK. I asked a similar question here last time and no one said anything, and I got an answer, so I assumed it was the place to do it. Will leave SO to programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

3.5.0.Final should be really stable. I expect it to be out in about 2-3 Weeks as we want to add some other stuff too.